# A large vase (lays / is laid) in the corner of our front hallway

Tags: verb-forms, word-difference

> A large vase **lays** in the corner of our front hallway.
>
> A large vase **is laid** in the corner of our front hallway.

Which is the right sentence?  Should I use *lays* or *is laid*?

Comment: Hi, Park - did you look up [the definition of "lay"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay)?  It means "to put or set down in place".  Is the vase putting something else in place?

Comment: Considering that an answer below has gotten three downvotes so far, I think maybe this *lays* or *is laid* is not a simple matter that just looking it up in dictionaries can solve the problem. Please do not close this question on that ground.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - No question that lie/lay/lain/laid are very confusing.  I do think that "*lay* is transitive" is one of the simpler parts of the whole ball of wax, though.  It would help if the original poster had included more context as to exactly what part of it was confusing him.

Comment: @stangdon: I just *had* to upvote your comment! I have actually encountered *the whole ball of wax* before (albeit rarely), but seeing it here prompted me to [look up the origin](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fUIFAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&dq=%22the+whole+ball+of+wax%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20whole%20ball%20of%20wax%22&f=false). If I learn one fascinating little snippet like that every day for the rest of my life, I shall be more than content! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Glad you enjoyed it!  I caution you, though, that [the "land lottery" explanation is considered extremely doubtful by many people](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-who5.htm).

Comment: Modern English users almost always use the verb "lay" when they should really use "lie". It is a current shift of usage that we all need to get used to. I will continue to use "lie" here. Technically "lay" is wrong here, but dictionaries tend to catch up on misuse after it becomes commonplace and finally deem it *acceptable*. I think that is what is going to happen here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of OP's constructions are particularly likely. The normal sense of ***to lay*** is (transitive) *to put something down carefully in a flat position*.

Thus (intransitive) *It lays in the corner* is generally considered nonstandard / uneducated - but ***to lay / to lie*** are probably the most awkward pair of irregular verbs in English, so [it's a fairly common error.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%20lays%20on%20the%20bed%22)

OP's alternative ***is laid*** in the corner is a present perfect *passive* usage meaning *is **placed** in the corner [by someone unspecified]*. It's grammatically valid, but in practice is an unlikely construction that would only normally occur when describing the action *as it happens*.

Even the "correct" version *It **lies** in the corner* doesn't really work with something like a vase (which would normally be thought of as being "upright" rather than "in a horizontal position". So it should be...

> *A large vase **stands** in the corner of our front hallway*

Present continuous *It **is standing** in the corner* and present perfect *It **is stood** in the corner* are also technically valid, but idiomatically unlikely in OP's context.

---

[Here](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/lay-vs-lie) is one of many webpages discussing ***lay/lie*** usage, but the take-home message from my answer is ***neither*** of these verbs are appropriate for OP's context.

Comment: "Nonstandard/uneducated", yet used by all major media outlets in the United States. I agree that it is wrong. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Octopus: I'm not too sure about "used by all major media outlets in the US". My link saying it's a "fairly common error" is to 317 instances of *He lays on the bed*, which has to be evaluated in the context of almost 4000 instances of *He **lies** on the bed*. So although one might say "uneducated" is a *subjective* assessment, I think it's reasonable to say "nonstandard" is a *literal, objective* designation.

Comment: ...also note the far more conclusive present continuous [He is laying on the bed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+is+laying+on+the+bed%22) with just 9 hits, compared to 3680 for the "correct" form [He is lying on the bed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+is+lying+on+the+bed%22).